# Highlight by coloring a div on page load (without using jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery

I just need to highlight a div by changing its background color for just a moment on page load. I dont want to include jQuery UI plugin just for this.

Is there is any way to do this just by pure jQuery 1.4?

Comment: Do you want any effect on the coloring? Otherwise just switch class on the div.

Comment: yaa i need effect on coloring. A basic one. Something like stackoverflow do when u check a question having ur answer.

Comment: jQuery cannot animate colours -- it needs the UI plugin.

Comment: @lonesomeday Hey i got my solution.. check answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
HTML:
<div id="div1" class="someclass">Text</div>

JQuery:
$("div.someclass").css("background-color":"red");
```

or

```
$("#div1").css("background-color":"red");
```

I use this often to make sure that the script is picking up the right element or an element.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("div").addClass("highlight");
    setTimeout(function() {$("div").removeClass("highlight");}, 500);


.highlight {
      background: red;
}
```

Comment: solution seems good... but this is not working :-(  $(function() 
{ 
 $('#updated').addClass('highlight').delay(500).removeClass('highlight');   
});

Comment: @piemesons You can't directly chain and use delay, edited above, which does work using setTimeout